# Prerender.io issue - getting '301' miss on everything, then 404 - Nginx + AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, nginx, single-page-application, prerender

I'm working to make an AngularJS e-commerce application of mine more SEO friendly so I'm working on getting Prerender.io up and running on the app.

My setup for hosting/serving files is with **nginx** from a docker container, hosted on AWS.

So far I've:

1. Altered my nginx.conf - [based on this official nginx.conf recommended by Prerender docs](https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802)

   ```
   server {
       listen 9001;
       server_name localhost;
       root /app;
       index index.html;

       location /store {  
           proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token RIDE(H9j9jdeRANDOMtoken;

           set $prerender 0;
           if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
               set $prerender 1;
           }
           if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
               set $prerender 1;
           }
           if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
               set $prerender 0;
           }
           if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
               set $prerender 0;
           }

           #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
           resolver 8.8.8.8;

           if ($prerender = 1) {
               #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
               set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
               rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
               proxy_pass http://$prerender;
           }

           expires -1;
           add_header Pragma "no-cache";
           add_header Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
           try_files $uri$args $uri /index.html =404;
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE:**

At suggestion of Prerender.io team member, I've hardcoded the redirect to be in `https` instead of `http` which was most likely the cause of that 301 issue.

Rewrote this line to fix: `rewrite .* /https://$host$request_uri? break;`

2. Added a `fragment` header tag

   `<meta name="fragment" content="!">`
3. Set special `$locationProvider` variables

   ```
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
   ```

When I share a page on facebook, to test the crawler, it registers on the prerender dashboard at least. (A good sign because at least its hitting prerender.io, so `$prerender` is being set to 1 in nginx and the right prerender token is getting set).

However I am getting 404.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and/or where I should focus my debugging efforts??

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright so on my setup I had to take out this check for `$http_user_agent` `Prerender`, that was causing it to break for some reason.

So I took out the following lines:

```
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
```

Then... BOOM! Problem solved.

**NOTE:**

The original issue I was having was that I was receiving `301 Miss` on every attempt to cache. This was because my SSL certificate (and/or DNS) was rejecting reroute attempts to an `http` page. Only `https` was allowed. So to fix that I just hardcoded `https` into the rewrite rule (replacing `$scheme`).

```
rewrite .* /https://$host$request_uri? break;
```

Hope that helps someone else down the line, thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped somebody!! @jpk